# Error: Minified React error #130 in production react app built using vite

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages, vite

So I keep getting this error when I deploy my react app to github pages and this error only shows in production and the app is working okay in the development mode and shows no errors

```
Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=object&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this?if yes, how?

Comment: Is it not working only when you run the build with the flag `mode` equals to `production`? (--mode production)